# EP 1544461A1 , A questionable modified prior art,

Tags: prior-art

When this application first published on Google?

The published application on Google is identical to published on EPO, and both are greatly different from what is on reputable USPTO, which cited the original from Taiwan, while Google and EPO didn't.

Do those difference cast doubt on EPO/ Google publications as both identical, EPO publication is a few months after USPTO, and EPO and Google don't cite the original national document which is cited in USPTO?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not "publish" patent documents. It just stores and allows retrieval of copies of patent documents previously published by either the USPTO or the EPO. Google does have its own way of presenting that data and puts the patent document itself and some of the legal history together. To see the actual patent document click Download PDF. The document you mention EP1544461 was filed in 2003

**EDITED**

You may be looking at another patent family filed by  a different inventor but with the same title. It resulted in the issuance of a Canada patent, an EP patent and a US patent (US8446028 B2) and does get priority from a TW application. The U.S. application was filed in 2010.